# Need Help in Changing Screen Orientation in Android

Tags: android, android-orientation

I want to change the screen orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa when the user rotates his Android mobile phone clockwise/anticlockwise. Can anyone help me how to achieve this? I do not know what event is fired when the user rotates his Android mobile phone.

For instance, when the user touches the button in UI, touch event is fired. So, when the user shakes his Android mobile phone, what is the event that is fired? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai, 
     I got Solution with the help of **Georgy Gobozov**, But that solution has to be refined as shown below to work it properly,

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     if(newConfig.equals(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE))
     {
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  
     }
     else if(newConfig.equals(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT))
     {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your AndroidManifest in activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Then you should override this method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}
```

And use search, this question is very popular.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with shaking the phone.

Comment: @ Gerogy Gobozov: pls refer the answer posted by me, I convey  my thanx to you, bcause u had showed the firing event that is onconfigurationchanged method.

Comment: @ShadowGod: Refer the answer posted by me

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Accelerometer extends Activity 
    implements AccelerometerListener{

    public void onShake(float force) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Phone shaked : " + force, 1000).show();
    }
 }
```

You can refer to below link

http://blog.androgames.net/85/android-accelerometer-tutorial/

Comment: @Kurnal Shah: Can u pls tell me, i have wrote this code and i rotated my device from clock wise to anticlock wise, but i have not got this toast message, pls tell me what i did wrong

Comment: @Tilsan The Fighter: you have gone through the below example that i have given link. please refer that

Comment: Shah: Thanx for ur help, i had implemented that in a very simple way given by Georgy Gobozov and pls refer the correct answer, i have posted it .